# ingress-nginx k8 settings configuring controller.customPorts

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

As per: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/

I'm trying to install ingress-nginx with custom ports, but it does not expose those ports when I pass in the `controller.customPorts` parameter. I think I'm not passing it in the right format. The documentation says

```
A list of custom ports to expose on the NGINX ingress controller pod. Follows the conventional Kubernetes yaml syntax for container ports.
```

Can anyone explain to me what that format should be?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they mean what shows up in Pod definitions:

```yaml
- port: 1234
  name: alan
```

Comment: How would I pass this in as an `--set controller.customPorts` argument?

Comment: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set shows the various options.

Comment: This is what I was after, thank you so much @coderanger

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of the `yaml` file configuration should be like this:

```
customPorts:
  - enable: true
    name: sftp
    nodePort: 31022
    port: 22
```

Comment: What is the reason — what was the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could peek at the json schema defined by the helm chart:

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/main/charts/nginx-ingress/values.schema.json#L298

```json
        "customPorts": {
          "type": "array",
          "default": [],
          "title": "The customPorts to expose on the NGINX Ingress Controller pod",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "$ref": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-json-schema/master/v1.29.0/_definitions.json#/definitions/io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort"
          },
          "examples": [
            [
              {
                "name": "http",
                "containerPort": 80,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "https",
                "containerPort": 443,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
```

But, if you are looking to expose additional ports at your service level, ie loadbalancer/nlb, you want to use `service.customPorts[]` which follow service port specs.